# Postgresql 8.3 duplicate rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a little problem with one query that I'm writing. I've a lot of joins, and a lot of columns that I extract, in the where clause I compare date column with the minimum value of the same table. But when I got a same date for two rows, I need to get only one row. The where clause is like that:

```
bt.da2 = (select min(btreg.da2) from bt btreg.....
```

the query results a lot of customers, every customer has that bt.da2 date. I need when one customer has two rows, with the same value of the bt.da2 , I need to take only one of the two rows, not the two.
I may not explained myself clear. Please if anyone have a little clue what I'm asking, and something is not clear, please ask me.

I'm using `PostgreSQL 8.3`

Regards,
Julian

Comment: You will need to provide more detail: the full statement you are using and possibly the `create table` statements for the tables involved. Ideally a SQLFiddle example that shows your current problem

Comment: I'll be happy to show it to you, there is no problem, but it involves  32 tables, I'cant show you the create table statements of all. Basically there is a products table, a customers table, a payments table, and bank transfer tables (the bt table in the example). I just take the products table, left join the bank transfer table, and because some customers have more than one bank transfers that are at a same date, that is why it shows me two or more rows, that thing I want to avoid. Is there a way to "say": if there are two transfers with same dates, just return one of them, doesn't matter who.

Comment: Do your tables have at least one unique key column (or a combination of columns) NOTE: you should at least add the definition of one of the tables to the question. NOTE 2: upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell with so little information, but I would try something like this:

```
select *
from (
  select product_id, -- assumed to be the primary key 
         ...
         row_number() over (partition by product_id order by bt.da2) as rn
  from products pr
    left join bt on bt.da2 = pr.some_col
) t
where rn = 1
```

the `row_number()` function is used to create consecutive numbers for each product. The outer `where` clause then picks the first one. You can change the `order by` in the window definition to influence which one you pick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Postgresql 8.4 do not support the function row_number() :(

Comment: @dna: yes it does. 8.4 was the first version where this was introduced.

Comment: my mistake, the server version is 8.3.13 :(

Comment: @dna: then you should update as soon as possible. 8.3 is no longer supported (and is quite old anyway as is 8.4)

Comment: thanks, but this is a decision that my bosses make, I've no power over there, and I'm seeking for solutions, twisting and sh*t to make the results they want from me :) ... with 8.3.13

Comment: @dna: then tell your boss that 8.3 does not get any **security** fixes anymore. And no more bugfixes regarding data corruption. And no more bugfixes regarding server crashes. And no more bugfixes ....

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sort out duplicate values of da2 using:

```
bt.da2 = (select distinct min(btreg.da2) from bt btreg.....
```

I tried this out using PostgreSQL 9.1, but I am sure the distinct keyword will work as expected in 8.4 as well.

Comment: The way the condition is structured, the sub-select has to return only a single row, so the distinct won't make a difference.

Comment: the min() function returns only one date. The problem is, when it begins to compare this date to the outer bt table, where I've two rows for a customer with the same date as the subquery returns